# How many integrals to add to find integral of circle with another circle touching internally?

Tags: calculus, integration, circles

[Here](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=2y%20less%20than%20or%20equal%20to%20x%5E2%2By%5E2%20less%20than%20or%20equal%20to%204)

Would it be three or more integrals? I think it is three, but I am not sure because then the upper arc of the smaller circle is not included.

Comment: First of all, you will probably need two integrands. Secondly, convert to polar coordinates. The upper arc **_will_** be included because it's less than **OR** equal to.

Comment: Thanks. If I use polar coordinates then the radius for the lower half-circle is from 0 to 2, but for the upper half it is from x^2+y^2=1 to 2?

Comment: Well no. Because if you're taking the area of the bigger circle and you're excluding the smaller circle in the bigger circle, you will need to come up with a way to do this. Remember when you took Calculus II and you had to take the area between two curves? Same idea.

Comment: I am in Calc II and so far for integrals like this we divided the area into 3-5 parts and then just added the integrals. But that's without polar coordinates.

Comment: you can still use Cartesian coordinate system if you want. cut the area into 2 part (x>0) and (x<0). For each area, integrate x first and integrate y.

Comment: Thank you! I am so stupid, I forgot that you can integrate x first...